# Migration from Play 2.4.6 to Play 2.5.9 Evolutions Issue

Tags: playframework, slick, playframework-evolutions

I am trying to migrate Play 2.4.6 to Play 2.5.9. I am using this seed template
https://github.com/mariussoutier/play-angular-require-seed

I am facing issues with Evolutions. When I start the server. its trying to apply all SQL files downs and then Ups

What seems to be going wrong with Play 2.5.9. Earlier I had tried migrating to 2.5.14 and there were hell lot of memory leak and threads getting creating. [Play Scala Slick 3.0 Connection Pool Issue | Play 2.4 vs Play 2.5 Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43897212/play-scala-slick-3-0-connection-pool-issue-play-2-4-vs-play-2-5-issues)

My dependancies build.sbt file looks like below

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
filters,
cache,
ws,
specs2 % Test,
evolutions,
// WebJars (i.e. client-side) dependencies
"org.webjars" % "requirejs" % "2.3.2",
"org.webjars" % "underscorejs" % "1.8.3",
"org.webjars" % "jquery" % "1.12.4",
"org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.7-1" exclude("org.webjars", "jquery"),
"org.webjars" % "angularjs" % "1.4.10" exclude("org.webjars", "jquery"),
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "2.0.2",
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "2.0.2",
// "com.typesafe.slick" % "slick_2.11" % "3.2.0",
"com.typesafe.play" % "play-mailer_2.11" % "5.0.0",
"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.1",
"com.github.nscala-time" % "nscala-time_2.11" % "2.16.0",
"org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "3.0.3",
"org.specs2" % "specs2-matcher-extra_2.11" % "3.8.9" % "test",
"org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpcore" % "4.4.6",
"org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.5.3",
"com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-s3" % "1.11.117",
"ai.api" % "libai" % "1.4.8",
"org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.16",
"org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "3.16",
"org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml-schemas" % "3.16",
"commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.5"
)
```

Comment: What is exactly the evolutions issue? Looking at your other question, apparently, you are mixing various slick (and play-slick) versions in the same project, which could potentially lead to problems. But here, at this specific, question, what is the problem? What do you expect and what is happening?

Comment: @marcospereira like i mentioned "its trying to apply all SQL files downs and then Ups". Idle behavior of the new migrated project should have been to simply start and running. but its try to apply evolutions when nothing has been changed in schemea.

Comment: This is how Play evolutions work: they run the `downs` section before running the `ups` section. Play also maintains its own database table to track down which evolutions were applied and which weren't yet. If you already have a database scheme in place, you can turn off evolutions and handle this manually.

Comment: @marcospereira I think you didn't understand. We already have evolutions in place from our previous version. So no changes in schema nothing. DB is not changed at all. So when I turn on the server with Play 2.5. It tries to apply downs till 1 sql file and then up while 2.4 starts like that.. This is the issue.